# What resources are available to turn into storable hypergolic on the Jovian moons

Tags: mission-design, lander, jupiter, isru

I was thinking about whether a mission utilizing ISRU on a lander to refuel a transfer craft.
However, I don't know how to figure out what materials are available in large quantity ON THE EQUATORIAL REGION of each moon.
(The mission would explore each significant moon one after another over multiple years, to analyse surface details and phenomena.)
I know about a lot of ISRU-able fuels, but I specifically want to figure out whether there are materials that could be easily to a set of either hypergolic or a decomposable monoprop.