# Surface Resource Distribution Across the Orbits of the Saturnian Moons

Tags: isru

I've posted questions before related to ISRU and/or resource harvesting in the Saturn system, given how low the velocity change is for inter-moon transfer.

- [What resources are available to turn into storable hypergolic on the Jovian moons](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/64071/12102)

However, I've never asked about WHAT the resource distribution is.
Specifically, I would like to know:
**Have studies been done analysing the distribution and usefulness of the surface resources of Saturn's moons**